# How to Render Video Frames easily in iOS like AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-processing, renderer

I'm trying to make a custom video render that streams RTP h264 video.

I first tried using AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer and it turns out to be quite good. Is very easy to use because I just need convert the streamed h264 video into CMSampleBuffer and enqueue the data to the DisplayLayer. The DisplayLayer does everything for me such as proper playback speed, resizing etc. However, the biggest problem is that I need to do some compositing and cropping on the video, and AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer doesn't support any of those operations.

So I tried out using Video Toolbox to decode the frames into raw buffers so that I could edit them easily using CoreImage or Accelerate framework provided by Apple. I could get the decoded frames (CVPixelBuffer/CVImageBuffer) but displaying them correctly has been really difficult for me.

```swift
func someFunctionOnView() {
  var outputCallback = VTDecompressionOutputCallbackRecord()
  outputCallback.decompressionOutputCallback = decompressionSessionDecodeFrameCallback
  outputCallback.decompressionOutputRefCon = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
                
  let status = VTDecompressionSessionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            formatDescription: desc,    
                                            decoderSpecification: decoderParameters,
                                            imageBufferAttributes: destinationPixelBufferAttributes,outputCallback: &outputCallback,
                                             decompressionSessionOut: &videoSessionM)
}

private func decompressionSessionDecodeFrameCallback(
  _ decompressionOutputRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, 
  _ sourceFrameRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, _ status: OSStatus, 
  _ infoFlags: VTDecodeInfoFlags, 
  _ imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer?, _ presentationTimeStamp: CMTime, 
  _ presentationDuration: CMTime) -> Void {
    
    let streamManager: ViewController = unsafeBitCast(decompressionOutputRefCon, to: ViewController.self)
    if status == noErr {
     
        if let img = imageBuffer {
            let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = img
      
            // Do some operations such as cropping or compositing etc.
            let output = resizePixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, cropX: 0, cropY: 0, 
              cropWidth: 300, cropHeight: 200, scaleWidth: 100, scaleHeight: 100)
       
            // NEED HELP
            // Render the frames in a timely manner onto a view or layer
        }
        
    }
}
```

Can I get some help or advice on the some questions?

1. Materials and help on how to display frames in a timely manner? Currently the frames plays to fast or too slow. Is there a open source program or book I could get a look on how video renderers works?
2. Is there any well known library on Swift that already provides the functionality I want? Or does Apple provide any framework that enables displaying CVPixelBuffer/CVImageBuffer properly.
3. Easier way to do operations on Videos. It seems that AVFoundation provided by apple doesn't have any functionality on working on h264 streams. Is there something I'm missing?
4. How to Convert CMTime to CFTimeInterval or other times so that I can preset the images using MTLCommandBuffer [present(_:atTime:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1442989-present)